# what should be the value of seasonal parameter s in statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAX() if my time series has weekly seasonality?

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting, arima

After decomposing my time series data using code below in python

```
dcompose=seasonal_decompose(ts['data'],freq=7).plot()
```

I see seasonality in the time series data and hence i used **SARIMAX** function with `s=7`. what should be the correct value of `s` and is there better way to check seasonality?